# What are good practices to parse tokens from a users input?

Tags: c++, command-pattern

I am implementing a system where the user should feed my program a command. I then split up the string of their input into tokens, delineated by spaces, stored in a vector.

My initial idea was to use a bunch of if-else statements to determine which command should be triggered based on their input. Something like so:

```
vector<string> userInput;

if (userInput[0] == "help") {
    //do something
} else if (userInput[0] == "exit") {
    //do something else
} else if (....) {
```

and so on. But this seems clumsy. Are there better practices for approaching a problem like this? I've already looked into implementing a Command pattern, and even while using it, it appears like I'll run into the same problem of parsing user input to instantiate/execute a specific command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't you learn about regular expression and/or finite state machines in university?

Comment: Didn't you come here to help answer my question? It's fine if I missed something, but jeez, at least give me a resource to look at.

Comment: @DeiDei https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: Consider this code on Code Review: [Input handling system using the command pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/55365/32691)

Comment: @LAD I was under the impression that C++ doesn't allow switch statements for strings?

Comment: ***C++ doesn't allow switch statements for strings?*** It does not. I second the `std::map` recommendation.

Comment: Here are two examples: https://godbolt.org/g/EK1Gnz with if-else and https://godbolt.org/g/nSxY5E with map. You can see how many asm comands generates compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `std::unordered_map` to store a mapping from the command name to its handler.

Example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// The command handlers.
void help(std::vector<std::string> const&);
void exit(std::vector<std::string> const&);

// CommandHandler is a pointer to a function.
using CommandHandler = void(*)(std::vector<std::string> const&);

// Maps a string to a function pointer.
using CommandHandlers = std::unordered_map<char const*, CommandHandler>;

// Associate command names with handlers. 
CommandHandlers const command_handlers{
    {"help", help},
    {"exit", exit},
    {"abort", [](auto&) { std::abort(); }} // Can use a stateless lambda.
};

void handle(std::vector<std::string> const& userInput) {
    auto found = command_handlers.find(userInput[0].c_str());
    if(found == command_handlers.end())
        ; // Handle invalid command.
    else
        found->second(userInput); // Invoke the command handler.
}
```

A plain array with linear or binary search can be used instead of `std::unordered_map` if the number of commands is small.

`std::function<void(std::vector<std::string> const&)>` can be used instead of plain function pointer to allow stateful lambdas or member functions as command handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your solution is super syntax-dense, so I'm going to have to spend a good chunk of time working through it. I'm not all too experienced with C++, as you may have already guessed.

Comment: @Aaron Added a couple of comments for you.

Comment: @Aaron a good chunk of the magic is buried in `std::map`. Here is some documentation you may find helpful: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map . The first is easier to read, but sometimes glosses over or omits details that may be important. The second link is more detailed and generally more correct, should you need a finer-grained understanding. It also often looks like it's written in Martian to the uninitiated

Comment: Sorry to intrude, @Aaron, but it's just to point out that Mr. Egorushkin is using a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), not a `std::map`. They are usually implemented (and behave) quite differently.

Comment: My apologies, so he is. Thank you for the save, @Bob__

Comment: @bob__ Thanks for the clarification. I've been digging through documentation and examples of std::unordered_map and it's quite interesting.